# Export orders from drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, export, drupal-commerce, commerce

I Have tried the Views Data Export module to export orders from a Drupal Commerce Kickstart installation. But the line items gets rendered as an html-table.

I am not sure if this is possible with the Views Export module, but I want to loop through each line item to achieve something like this:

```
<order ordernr="1">
     <customer_profile id="1">
        ...
     </customer_profile>

    <line_items>
        <line_item sku="786">
            <price>100</price>
        </line_item>

etc...

    </line_items>

</order>
```